# Unable to scroll using EarlGrey scroll actions

Tags: swift, earlgrey

I am unable to scroll on the initial state of a tableview.  When reaching the page with a long table, I attempt to scroll down using `scrollInDirection()` but I receive an error (`cannot scroll, scrollview is already at edge`). If I perform a `swipeUp()` action and then attempt scrolling, I am able to scroll up and down with the same code. I cannot figure out how to scroll without the unnecessary swipe actions.

Code to scroll:

```
EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_kindOfClass(UITableView.self)).perform(grey_scrollInDirection(GREYDirection.down, 300))
```

Error received:

```
"NSLocalizedDescription" : "Cannot scroll, the scrollview is already at the edge"
```

Comment: Scrolling will not continue if the view is already at the top since EG doesn't allow needless scrolling. Why are you doing a scroll? Do you need to find an element after scrolling?

You can use the usingSearchAction: method for this purpose.

Comment: The table is plenty long to scroll, there are many elements out of view and I am unable to click them with out precise scrolling. I have tried the usingSeachAction and receive the same error